# Use HTTP traffic for internal communication in WSO2 API Management across all components

Tags: kubernetes, wso2-api-manager, kubernetes-ingress

We have a setup of WSO2 API Management in a distributed pattern (pattern-3) in Kubernetes. By default all components of WSO2 APIM (Publisher, Key Manager, Store, Traffic Manager, Gateway) are using HTTPS protocol for inter-process communication.

The ingress is fronted by a loadbalancer which exposes HTTPS traffic. The ingress setup exposes only HTTP traffic to services within the cluster.

What changes will be required to ensure that only HTTP traffic flows in the services i.e.

- Between Ingress and individual components (Publisher,Gateway, Store)
- Between components (Publisher to Keymanager, Store to Key Manager etc.)

Comment: it is still unclear why you want to switch from HTTPS to HTTP?

Comment: @VasilyAngapov, we want to set this up only for our non-prod environment. The components are running in a secured zone. We do not want to have additional overhead of HTTPS within this zone.